# Jupyter notebook does not read existing config file

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a new jupyter notebook setup which is not correctly reading the config file. The config file was generated with `jupyter notebook --generate-config`, which confirmed that the file is correctly located at `/home/username/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`. In the config file, I have set only the following lines:

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShellApp.matplotline = "inline"
c.InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs={'facecolor':'w'}
```

But when I open a new notebook, the plots are not inline and the background color of generated plots is still transparent.

These commands have worked for me in previous environments. I have also tried adding nonsense lines to the config file that should lead to an error, but do not, so for some reason jupyter notebook is not reading the config file that it generated for itself.

I've also confirmed that `jupyter_core.paths.jupyter_config_path()` correctly includes the '/home/username/.jupyter` folder.

Any advice would be appreciated.